# Booting from USB when BIOS doesn't support it?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, bios

I'm pretty sure my BIOS doesn't support booting from a flash drive. I know my flash drive is bootable and already has installed Ubuntu on it. Is there any way to get my computer to boot from the flash drive without flashing the BIOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Burn [PLOP boot manager](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager.html) to a cd. This is effectivly a bootloader on a disc that will detect bootable interfaces.

Answer (score 6):

Check this out from Ubuntu forums:

[HOWTO: Boot from USB Flash Drive using Grub](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992426).

The HOWTO describes booting from a CD-ROM first with GRUB setup to boot the flash drive.

Comment: That's perfect.